# Rのlowessfunctionについて

Tags: r

R言語(version 3.3.1)でlowessを使っています。

lowess機能で少し変更をしたい点がありましたので、自作を行いたいです。

具体的には、Rのcommand lineでlowessとタイプしますと、以下のようなコードが出てきます。

```
function (x, y = NULL, f = 2/3, iter = 3L, delta = 0.01 * diff(range(x))) 
{
    xy <- xy.coords(x, y)
    o <- order(xy$x)
    x <- as.double(xy$x[o])
    list(x = x, y = .Call(C_lowess, x, as.double(xy$y[o]), f, 
        iter, delta))
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000caf1858>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

ここでxに関してのorderをせずにlowessを行いたいです。
まず初めにこのfunctionが機能するかを確かめるために、
このlowessのfunction自体をコピーし、mylowessとして新たにfunctionを作成し、実行しました。その結果、

```
Error: object 'C_lowess' not found
```

というエラーメッセージが出てきました。

自分の理解では、Rの各functionを改変し、新にfunctionとして再利用することは可能だと思っていました。今までいつくものfunctionを作成できていました。しかし、今回このようなエラーが出てしまい、googleで調べましたが、ヒントらしきものがヒットされませんでしたので、ここで質問させていただいています。

もしこのようなエラーを解決する方法をご存じでしたら、ご教授をお願いします。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

mylowess内の該当箇所を`stats:::C_lowess`に変更すると機能するかと思います。
`C_lowess`関数を{stats}から明示的に取り出す、という記述です。

Comment: 返信が大変遅くなり、申し訳ありません。情報ありがとうございました。